# Does capillary action work in moving bodies?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, water, capillary-action

If I were to have a capillary tube on a moving body such as an ocean buoy, would it still be able to draw the liquid upwards? Or would the turbulence slow down or stop capillary action?

Answer (score 0):

For capillarity to act, the scale length for the capillaries is necessarily so small and the velocities so low that viscosity clamps inertia, and turbulence cannot get established.

On an object like a buoy subject to heaving motion with period ~seconds, capillarity will still work but the vertical accelerations will look like cyclic changes in G to the fluid in the capillaries. This means the surface tension force balance against gravity acting on the mass of entrained fluid will go back and forth, causing the interface to rise and fall. That motion will be superimposed on the rise of fluid in the capillaries.

A more accurate picture can be modeled by taking the advancing and retreating contact angles into account at the interface, where the once-wetted capillary is more easily rewetted on the next heave of the buoy.

Comment: So to clarify, you are saying that fluid will rise and fall in the capillaries because of the heaving motion.

Comment: yes, but only slightly as the time constant for capillary movement is longer than  the heaving period.

Comment: But will the liquid be able to reach its maximum height? Or will the heaving stop it?

Comment: the heaving will make the interface oscillate around its maximum height point.